# How to render volume data into a 3D texture using OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, volume, voxel

I'm trying to render some 3D shapes into a 3D texture using the GPU. I am using Framebuffer objects to accomplish this. The only way I have found so far that works is by rendering to one slice (or layer) of the 3D texture at a time.

For example, if I want to draw a sphere to the 3D texture, I would draw the appropriate cross-section of the sphere to each layer of the texture.

This works fine at small resolutions or for small number of shapes, but quickly slows as resolution or complexity increases.

Is there some more correct or faster approach? I'm targeting moderately old hardware so I'm limited to OpenGL 3.x. Specifically, I can't use some of [the techniques described here](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~pcozzi/OpenGLInsights/OpenGLInsights-SparseVoxelization.pdf).

Comment: It seems that, where available, using `imageStore` in the fragment shader is the right answer. Instead of drawing a cross section of my shape for every slice of the volume, I can simply render the shape to a plane (let's say the x-y plane), then for each "fragment", I can compute the z-interval of my shape and simply `imageStore` the correct coordinates in the 3D texture. The question of how to do this efficiently on hardware that does not allow such control remains open.

Answer (score 1):

While I haven't personally done this, I know of an example that has a solution for directX. It may be portable to OpenGL: [Generating Complex Procedural Terrains Using the GPU](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch01.html), see section 1.3.2: Generating the Density Values.

In short, do an instanced draw, and direct each instance to a different layer of the texture.

You may also be able to duplicate all your triangles and send them to all relevant slices with a geometry shader.

Comment: Good advice, but this seems to invoke the fragment shader the same number of times as my approach (though it might be more efficient because of fewer draw calls). For now, I decided to try it with imageStore in OpenGL 4.2.

Comment: You may be able to combine my initial idea with clip planes to discard the unneeded fragments before the fragment shader gets run. This is possible in HLSL (so I assume GLSL supports it too) and generally happens at the same time as early depth test (as part of selecting which fragments to shade).